# How to read the partitions in an external hard disc which is used to create a recovery folder

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive

I have 500 gb external HDD, recently I have been trying to create a recovery disc for my laptop. hence I chose one of the partitions (it has 4 partitions) in my external hdd to create one. it so happened that it has created a recovery folder of 31 gb and the remaining partitions in the hdd vanished off the screen.
I had nearly 400 gb of data in my external hdd.
kindly suggest how to recover the contents in other partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of a Linux OS like Ubuntu. Burn the image to a DVD. Boot to the disc, and select try Ubuntu. Then insert your external hard dive into your computer. If you can see your drive in Ubuntu, copy the data you want to your windows partition.

Ubuntu Download Link: [Ubuntu OS Image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)